# Need to route to another activity when different links in a textview are clicked

Tags: java, android, xml, textview

Right now I have a texview that's being generated by pulling a large paragraph from a database. This paragraph gives an overview, and should have multiple links in it to another view. I.e., the paragraph will say something like:

```
Angry Birds is a fun app. 
Flappy Birds is a frustrating app.
```

But in the database, there is something along the lines of this:

```
[**Angry Birds**](/app_reviews/3326) is a fun app. 
[**Flappy Birds**](/app_reviews/4458) is a frustrating app.
```

Basically, this paragraph will have descriptions about different "apps", and when you click on the name of the app, it should open up another activity that is a review of the app. The name of the app in the paragraph should be underlined or another color, like a link.

So far, I've come to the conclusion that since this is a large paragraph of text in a single textview, I'd like to parse the string before it enters the text view and insert an href link to the other activity, passing the review id to the new view. Is this a viable way of doing this? So far, if I include the link to the new activity and I click on it, I get a "Unfortunately, the  has stopped working" message. I believe it isn't linking correctly.

Here is a snippet of my AndroidManifest.xml file with the activity I want to link to:

```xml
    <activity
        android:name="com.myapp.myappname.AppReviewActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_app_review" >
        <intent-filter>
            <data android:host="linkreview" android:scheme="appreviewactivity" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Here is the code in my original activity where I am hosting my textview:

```java
    TextView categoryBlurb = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.categoryBlurb);
    categoryBlurb.setText(Html.fromHtml("<html>This is an app link to <a href=\"appreviewactivity://linkreview?id=3326\">Angry birds</a><html>"));
    categoryBlurb.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

and this is the AppReviewActivity.java code:

```java
    public class AppReviewActivity extends BaseActivity {

    private AppReview review;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_app_review);
            Uri passedData = getIntent().getData();
    if (passedData != null) {
        String reviewIdString = passedData.getQueryParameter("id");
        long reviewId = Long.valueOf(reviewIdString).longValue();
        review = Main.database.FindOne(AppReview.class, "app_reviews", reviewId);
    }
```

Is there something I'm doing terribly wrong here? I'm fairly new to android. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to accomplish what you are trying to do would be to use a fragment.  When the user clicks on an item retrieve whatever data you need and then pass the data to the fragment using one of multiple ways.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? Do you mean to pull out each link as a fragment somehow and redirect the user? Do you have any links to tutorials or overviews that fit my needs?